# SQLAlchemy expression language: how to join table with subquery?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a subquery table `inner_stmt`, which I want to join with a table `revisions`. But `revisions.join()` gives the following error:

```
Neither 'Label' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'c'
```

Here is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
inner_stmt = select([
        ratings.c.article_name,
        func.min(ratings.c.timestamp).label('mintime')]) \
    .group_by(ratings.c.article_name).label('firstga')

stmt = select([
        revisions.c.article_id,
        func.max(revisions.c.length_bytes)]) \
    .select_from(revisions.join(
        inner_stmt,
        revisions.c.article_name == inner_stmt.c.article_name)) \
    .group_by(table.c.article_id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are [`label`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.SelectBase.label)ing your subquery `inner_stmt`. `label` is for columns or expressions, i.e. `SELECT ... AS ...`. You want [`alias`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.alias) instead, which is for subquery expressions, i.e. `FROM ... AS ...`. You cannot access columns (`.c.<name>`) from the former, even in SQL, because it's a SQL expression.

Comment: Ah, so simple! Thanks.